# How to override a render function in dc.js

Tags: dc.js

I'd like to customize the rendering of the grid lines in a dc.js line chart. For this I need to override some functions in the coordinate-grid-mixin, but not all of them seem to be exposed.

I have successfully overridden the render function for horizontal grid lines in my custom chart with

```
dc.override(_chart, '_renderHorizontalGridLinesForAxis', ...)
```

But for vertical gridlines this doesn't seem possible as the function `renderVerticalGridLines` is not exposed in the chart. How do I override this function?

Comment: Doesn't look like you can do that currently. Feel free to open a PR exposing `renderVerticalGridLines` the way the other function is exposed.